# When clicking on 'typeset', preview does not appear

Tags: texshop

I'm using TexShop 4.24 and pdfTeX on macOS 10.14.3

In the past, when i click on 'typeset', or Command T, a preview window of the pdf pops up. However, recently when clicking on 'typeset', i get the pop up to save the file as a pdf.

If i open my old files, the 'typeset' button works to open a preview. New files face the issue above though.

Would appreciate any advice!

Comment: I'm not sure since I don't use it but *maybe* your file has no `.tex` extension.

Comment: Does the pdf actually get generated? Try a really basic document: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello World.
\end{document}`.

Comment: @Peter Yes the pdf is generated.

Comment: @sigur Hi, this helped! Thank you. However, this means i always have to rename my document with .tex extension before the preview window would work for me. Would you know how i can set it as default .tex whenever i create a new file so i don't have to rename the files always?

Comment: I don't use that editor. But I think that if you type a full file name first time you save it, you don't need to do anything extra later, it should work. Maybe the editor has this feature, to automatically insert the extension, or maybe not. Check its configuration tools.